# Node read data from file line by line ... process it and save it back issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a file I have data that looks like this:

```
id=1349 console.log('done this') status=waiting
id=2345 console.log('done this too') status=waiting
```

If will read a line at the time, then change status to complete and save it back to the file.

So this is what I've got:

```
fs.readFile('list.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {

  if (data.includes('status=waiting')) {

    const str = data.trim();
    const arr = str.replace(/;$/gm, '').split(/\n/g)

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      var result = arr[i].replace('status=waiting', 'status=complete');

      var temp = result.split(" ");
      console.log(temp[1]);
      eval(temp[1]); //run the console.log

      console.log(`RESULT IS: ${result}`); // This line should now have status=complete when it saves below

      // Now Save it back with the status=complete in it
      fs.writeFile('list.txt', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
      });


    };


  }

});
```

The problem is the saving... Although variable result is correct before saving, it's just replacing the file text and only saving the last one.

How can I fix this?

*ps: I know eval shouldn't be used but this is just for personal use.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write to a file, you can't right line by line, you write the whole content. For a line by line approach, you probably want to use [fs.appendfile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback), which as the method states, just appends the line onto the file but doesn't remove the initial line. So that probable won't work for you.

So, I think what you want it something like

- Read the entire file content
- Parse into an array of each line
- Walk through each line
- If the `status=waiting`, replace with `status=complete`
- Finally, save the entire content back into the same file

```
  fs.readFile("list.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }

    const dataByLine = data.toString().split("\n");

    const newData = dataByLine.map(line => {
      if (line.includes("status=waiting")) {
        const newLine = line.replace("status=waiting", "status=complete");

        return newLine;
      }

      return line;
    });

    const result = newData.join("\n");

    fs.writeFile("list.txt", result, "utf8", err => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);

      console.log('The file has been saved!');

    });
  });
```

PS - This doesn't include any of your eval loggings. Did it just showing you a step in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, you can append using `writeFile`, using `{'flag':'a'}`. Although he shouldn't do that, since using streams is a better approach for writing "line by line"

Comment: Fair point, but he's not trying to append the file, right? He's trying to update a specific line.

Comment: I was addressing your comment, not what OP wanted. `"for a line by line a approach  you probably want to use fs.appendfile"`, a stream is better suited for that.